# Can't save same data using ObjectBox with Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, objectbox

I'm using ObjectBox to save data. When I save the same data with ToMany, it only save the first one.

- ObjectBox(version:2.0.0)
- Android(target sdk version:27)
- Kotlin(version:1.2.60)

Here is my code.

```
@Entity
data class Order(@Id var id: Long = 0,
                 val createTime: Long = 0,
                 val total: Int = 0) {

    @Backlink(to = "order")
    lateinit var details: ToMany<OrderDetail>
}

@Entity
data class OrderDetail(@Id var id: Long = 0,
                       val productName: String = "",
                       val productSpecName: String = "",
                       val productSpecPrice: Int = 0,
                       val quantity: Int = 0,
                       val subtotal: Int = 0) {

    lateinit var order: ToOne<Order>
}
```

The test

```
@Test
    fun orderDetailTest() {

        val orderBox = store.boxFor(Order::class.java)

        // 儲存兩個內容相同的資料
        val order = Order().apply {
            this.details.add(OrderDetail(productSpecName = "ABC"))
            this.details.add(OrderDetail(productSpecName = "ABC"))
        }

        val orderId = orderBox.put(order)

        val result = orderBox.get(orderId)

        assert(result.details.size == 2)
    }
```

The size of result.details is 1.

Can I save multiple same data with ToMany? How can I fix it?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: I just remove the keyword 'data' with entity, it's work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kotlin data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) provide among others a custom implementation for `hashCode()`. `ToMany` uses a `HashMap` to keep track of entities to add or remove. I guess you can see where this is going:

Based on the Kotlin data class implementation if two data classes have the same properties, their hash codes match. Now given this example with two identical `OrderDetail` data classes according to their `hashCode()`:

```
val order = Order().apply {
    this.details.add(OrderDetail(productSpecName = "ABC"))
    this.details.add(OrderDetail(productSpecName = "ABC"))
}
```

Two entities will be added to the `ToMany` list. However, the internal change tracking mechanism assumes that the second entity replaces the first one, because `HashMap` believes they are the same. Hence only one gets added.

**Making `OrderDetail` a regular class (remove the `data` keyword)** drops the custom `hashCode()` implementation and everything works as expected.

I believe in Kotlin two data classes that share the same properties are considered to be "the same", so this behavior is kind of expected. Though I agree it is unintuitive. Not sure what we should do here.

[Related GitHub Issue](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/528)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the OrderDetail id, otherwise its always 0 at default and will override the previous order detail.

```
val orderDetail = OrderDetail(id = 1, productSpecName = "ABC")
orderDetail.order = order
this.details.add(orderDetail)
val orderDetail2 = OrderDetail(id = 2, productSpecName = "ABC")
orderDetail2.order = order
this.details.add(orderDetail2)
```