# Objectbox doesn't store nullable value in one to many relation

Tags: flutter, objectbox, flutter-objectbox, greenrobot-objectbox

I have this one to many relation which looks like this.

```
@Entity()
class Product {
  @Id()
  int id;
  String name;
  String category;
  int categoryId;
  WeightType weightType;
  double? price;
  double weight;
  bool isRefunded;

  Product({
    this.id = 0,
    required this.name,
    required this.category,
    required this.categoryId,
    this.weightType = WeightType.kg,
    this.price,
    this.weight = 0,
    this.isRefunded = false,
  });

  Product copy() => Product(
        name: name,
        category: category,
        id: id,
        price: price,
        weight: weight,
        weightType: weightType,
        categoryId: categoryId,
        isRefunded: isRefunded,
      );

  String getInfo(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        return name;
      case 2:
        return price.toString();
      case 3:
        return weight.toString() + ' ' + weightType.getName();
      case 4:
        if (weightType == WeightType.kg) {
          return (price! * weight).toString();
        } else {
          return (price! * (weight / 1000)).toString();
        }
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
}
```

```
@Entity()
class Pdf {
  @Id()
  int id;
  Uint8List pdfData;
  final String customerName;
  @Property(type: PropertyType.date)
  final DateTime purchaseDate;
  ToMany<Product> products; //<----------- the relation
  double totalAmount;
  PaymentStatus paymentStatus;
  @Property(type: PropertyType.date)
  DateTime? updateDate;

  Pdf({
    this.id = 0,
    required this.pdfData,
    required this.purchaseDate,
    required this.customerName,
    required this.totalAmount,
    required this.products,
    this.paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.unPaid,
    this.updateDate,
  });

  int get status => paymentStatus.index;

  set status(int value) {
    paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.values[value];
  }
}
```

now how I am adding data to `db`,

```
void addToDb(Bill bill){
final billPdf = Pdf(
      pdfData: pdf,
      purchaseDate: DateTime.now(),
      customerName: bill.customerName,
      totalAmount: bill.totalAmount,
      paymentStatus: bill.paymentStatus,
      products: obj.ToMany(items: bill.products) //<------- this is the product list
    );
    DBService.pdfBox.put(billPdf,mode: obj.PutMode.insert);
}
```

now before executing `Dbservice.pdfbox.put()`

[image]

afterexecuting `Dbservice.pdfbox.put()`

[image]

you can see that `price` and `weight` are not null and also `RelInfo` is also not null(it has one parameter which is null)

Now when I fetch data from db, I get all the data same as I put except the nullable variables or a variable which contains default value. which are `price`, `weight` and 'weightType`.

which you can see here,

[image]

Lastly, this how I created objectbox `store`,

```
class DBService {
  static late final Store store;

  static late final Box<Product> productBox;

  static late final Box<Category> categoryBox;

  static late final Box<Pdf> pdfBox;

  DBService._();

  static Future<void> create() async {
    store = await openStore();
    productBox = store.box();
    categoryBox = store.box();
    pdfBox = store.box();
  }
}
```

calling `create()` in `main()`

If I put `final pdf = ToOne<Pdf>()` in product model then question which I asked earlier happens all over again.

which is this -> [how to add same object in objectbox's box multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591578/how-to-add-same-object-in-objectboxs-box-multiple-times)

Now can you guys tell me why only nullable/which has default values are not getting stored in objectbox db?

Comment: I wrote a test for this using your entites and it works as expected. Are you sure that those properties are in the generated model (e.g. check `lib/objectbox-model.json`)? Maybe you need [to run the generator](https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#generate-objectbox-code), e.g. using `flutter pub run build_runner build`.

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox yes `.json` file does contain all the properties. In relations, `Pdf` has one but `Product`'s relation list is empty is that expected? And I am so confused because it only doesn't store nullable or a property which has default value and all other are stored

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox I'm using `1.4.1` if that matters

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox can you share anything which you might have assumed I have done it and implemented it in you test because I'm really stuck at this for 3-4 days and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here in my both questions

Comment: The changes I made to the ObjectBox Dart example: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/compare/so-71637219-value-not-stored You also may want to look at https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started#object-ids and https://docs.objectbox.io/relations